# how can i avoid loading again same screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have login and registration items in PopupMenuItem. when the login screen is opened then if I tap again the login item it will again the login screen. I want to prevent from open the login screen if it already opened. how can I will deal with this issue

Comment: Show screenshots.

Comment: I'm not able to share image in comment. I put just the code below. 

 Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
    );

this is my code if login screen or any other screen currently opened then it should be not open again.

Comment: Normally, you would just remove the element that navigates to the login screen, if you already are in the login screen.

Comment: how can I will check that I'm already on login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `pushReplacement`

```
Navigator.pushReplacement( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
```

Comment: Sorry Sir it's not working. still load screen again and again. if I tap it three times then on back button it displayed login page. after three time tap on back button then show me home page.

Comment: Please record a video and send in  google drive link. I actually don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: Please find the following link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RMC8yp_aClFblb5hUTZ2geAP33fs3qGn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share the code? I unterstood your issue but I need to see the code to fix it.

Comment: Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
    );

Comment: Navigator.pushReplacement( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));

Comment: restart app to see the changes

Comment: I have done pushReplacement but whenever I click on the back button  instead redirect to back page the app has been closed.

Comment: class _LoginPopupState extends State<LoginPopup> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return  PopupMenuButton<int>(
      itemBuilder: (context) => [
        PopupMenuItem(
            value: login,
            child: Text('Login'),
        ),
        ],
      onSelected: (value) => choiceAction(value, context),
    );
  }
}

void choiceAction(int choice, BuildContext context){
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
    );
}

Comment: Sorry! I won't understand. I need to see the full code. Could you share the project?

Comment: pls send me Skype id. here are restriction of words.