# The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("id")

Tags: json, flutter

I want to get user data from SharedPreferences in json format. whenever I want to show this data in screen it will show on screen but in console it displayed this error "The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: ".
the error are throwing by this code ${userData['id']}

```
class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  var userData;
  void initState(){
    getUserData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getUserData() async{

    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     var userJson =  localStorage.getString('user');
     var user = json.decode(userJson);
     setState(() {
       userData = user;
     });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text("Profile"),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[LoginPopup()],
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body:Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('${userData['id']}'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[this is the error show in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fecww.png)

[this will display the id but error is still in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uly5N.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this happens because the first time you render your widget, you display `userData` which is null because you did not initialize the `userData` variable.
So you can initialize it from the start like that

```
var userData = { "id": 0 };
```

or you can make a condition if `userData` is null like this

```
Text(userData != null ? "${userData['id']}" : "0")
```

But then, you call `setState` and it will rebuild your widget and `userData` is no longer `null` because you get user data from SharedPreferences.

Comment: Upvote done. please check my another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701164/how-can-i-avoid-loading-again-same-screen-in-flutter